# tera termマクロでのコマンド実行確認

Tags: teraterm

tera termマクロで、sendln hoge とやると
コマンドを実行してくれますが、
これにユーザーの実行承認をつけることは可能でしょうか？

例えば
$ myapp status
myapp is runnning…
$myapp stop←ここで、enterキーを押すまで、実行させないようにしたい

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

１．ダイアログで一時停止する（必要であればyesnoboxを使う）

```
messagebox '処理を続行します。' '確認'
```

２．コマンドの文字列だけ送信して、Enterの入力後の表示文字列を待機する。

```
send 'stop'
wait 'Enter後の文字'
```

３．「stop」は手入力させて、それを待つ

```
wait 'stop'
```

上記の様なやり方はどうでしょうか？
Enterをキー指定で待機するのは無いと思います。

Comment: 望んだ通りの動作になりました！ありがとうございます！